# PHPUnit: Expected status code 200 but received 419 with Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I want to test the delete method but I am not getting the expected results from PHPUnit. I receive this message when running the test:

```
 Expected status code 200 but received 419. Failed asserting that false is true.
 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:77
 /tests/Unit/CategoriesControllerTest.php:70
```

Laravel version: 5.5

Thank you for any help!

Controller constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware('categoryAccess')->except([
        'index',
        'create'
    ]);
}
```

Controller method:

```
public function destroy($categoryId)
{
    Category::destroy($categoryId);

    session()->flash('alert-success', 'Category was successfully deleted.');

    return redirect()->action('CategoriesController@index');
}
```

categoryAccess middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $category = Category::find($request->id);

    if (!($category->user_id == Auth::id())) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Category model:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'deleted' => CategoryDeleted::class,
];
```

Event listener

```
public function handle(ExpensesUpdated $event)
{
    $category_id = $event->expense->category_id;

    if (Category::find($category_id)) {
        $costs = Category::find($category_id)->expense->sum('cost');

        $category = Category::find($category_id);

        $category->total = $costs;

        $category->save();
    }
}
```

PHPUnit delete test:

```
use RefreshDatabase;

protected $user;

public function setUp()
{
   parent::setUp();
   $this->user = factory(User::class)->create();
   $this->actingAs($this->user);
}

/** @test */
public function user_can_destroy()
{
    $category = factory(Category::class)->create([
        'user_id' => $this->user->id
    ]);

    $response = $this->delete('/category/' . $category->id);

    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $response->assertViewIs('category.index');
}
```

Comment: It's an authentication problem, try with `$this->withoutMiddleware();` just to see if it will be OK !!

Comment: Hi thanks, I added that to the method and ran the test again and I get this message now: Expected status code 200 but received 302.

Comment: Try this time the treat `use WithoutMiddleware;` in the PHPUnit Class and don't forget to import it  `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;`

Comment: Thank you @Maraboc $this->withoutMiddleware(); works! The thing is this test is supposed to expect status code 302 I found out by reading an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117088/returns-302-error-in-phpunit-when-the-site-redirection-works-fine).

Comment: That's good to know ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sometimes in testing you will need to disable middlewares to proceed :

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class ClassTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware; // use this trait

    //tests here
}
```

and if you want to disable them just for one specific test use :

```
$this->withoutMiddleware();
```

Comment: This works, except in cases where a Middleware is actually part of your tests.

Answer (score 55):

**Solution**: When you cached your configuration files you can resolve this issue by running `php artisan config:clear`.

**Explanation**: The reason why this can resolve the issue is that PHPUnit will use the cached configuration values instead of the variables defined in your testing environment. As a result, the `APP_ENV` is not set to testing, and the `VerifyCsrfTokenMiddleware` will throw a `TokenMismatchException` (Status code 419).

It won't throw this exception when the `APP_ENV` is set to testing since the `handle` method of `VerifyCsrfTokenMiddleware` checks if you are running unit tests with `$this->runningUnitTests()`.

It is recommended not to cache your configuration in your development environment. When you need to cache your configuration in the environment where you are also running unit tests you could clear your cache manually in your `TestCase.php`:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan; 

public function createApplication()
{
    ....
    Artisan::call('config:clear')
    ....
}
```

Example based on https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13374#issuecomment-239600163

Read more about configuration caching in this [blog post](https://arievisser.com/blog/configuration-caching-caveats-in-laravel/) or the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching).

Comment: This worked for me also, but why does this fix the problem?

Comment: @DarrenFindlay I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The message here is indeed related to the CSRF middleware. But there is a much better way of attacking this problem than disabling the middleware.

The middleware comes with code built-in that detects if it is being used in a test. This check looks for 2 things:

- Am I being ran via a command line
- Am I being ran in an environment type of `testing`

Default, proper setup of the software correctly causes both flags to be true when running PHP unit. However, the most likely culprit is the value in your `APP_ENV`. Common ways for this to to be incorrect include:

- Misconfigured `phpunit.xml` file. It should contain `<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing" />`
- A shell session that has an explicit value set in `APP_ENV` that overrides this value
- A Docker/docker-compose/kubernetes session that has an explicit value set in `APP_ENV`. Seeing about getting this value set via the .env and/or phpunit.xml files is perhaps better if possible. Or ensuring the build/test process sets the value.

This one stumped me as well and I was not convinced that I would need the use of `WithoutMiddleware` since I did not for a different project, but it turned out I had experimented with something on the command line and overrode `APP_ENV` in bash.

Answer (score 4):

This is the exact solution:

Laravel environment will set after bootstraping application, so you cant change it from appServiceProvider or another source.
for fix this error you need to add this function to App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if(env('APP_ENV') !== 'testing')
        {
            return parent::handle($request, $next);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

you need to use env('APP_ENV') that is set in .env.testing file with

```
APP_ENV=testing
```

Answer (score 1):

This is according to my experience, I switch the program to static

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:cache
```

and this resulted in csrf running, so I changed it to original mode

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the file `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` by adding:

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
{
    if ('testing' !== app()->environment())
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/trouble-testing-http-verbs-with-phpunit-in-laravel/replies/29878