# Getting status 419 running a phpunit test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a weird issue that i don’t understand entirely. I’m running a test but a I’m getting a `419`

```
$member = factory(User::class)->create([ 'type' => 'member' ]);
$title = "Random Title for Test.";
$case = factory(DentalCase::class)->raw(['title' => $title]);

$response = $this->actingAs($member)->post('/cases/create', $case);

$response->assertStatus(302);
$this->assertDatabaseHas('cases', ['title' => $title,]);
```

Error Response: `Response status code [419] is not a successful status code.`

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46326721/4881811) hope it will helps you :)

Comment: Would you show us the method recieving the POST request?

Comment: @Maraboc I know that a "solution" but on my co-worker's computer it works fine without any modifications. Same branch, both serving with Valet.

Comment: @Camilo yeah, `return [ 'created' => true];` just that, I removed everything else.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with you local evironment being local and not testing, hence phpunit clashing with it. This line in your phpunit.xml

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true" />
```

need to be set in `.env.testing` to 'testing'

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. “This line in your phpunit.xml” what line are you referencing? The OP didn't shared the `phpunit.xml` file.

Comment: phpunit.xml gets pulled in to php project and this is where variables needed to be added to and environment variable file are listed.

Comment: Could you please share the code that should be in the `.env.testing` file?

Comment: APP_ENV=testing

Comment: Oh I understand now, the line is in the answer but was not visible because it was treated as HTML. Let's fix it.