# 419 Page Expired with Laravel Octane, Sail, Sanctum and Dusk

Tags: laravel, octane, sanctum

After migration to Laravel Octane, the dusk tests fails with 419 Page Expired. Before the migration, everything was fine...

I made the following change to the name file docker/8.1/supervisord.conf

```
-command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan octane:start --server=swoole --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
+command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

- Laravel Version: 8.82.0
- Laravel Sanctum: 2.14.0
- Octane Version: 1.2.0
- Dusk Version: 6.22.0
- PHP Version: 8.1.1
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 8
- OS: macOS 12.2

My part of `.env.local.dusk` file:

```
APP_ENV=local
OCTANE_SERVER=swoole
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=laravel.test
```

My the dusk test:

```
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser
                ->visit(new Login())
                ->loginUser($user->email, 'password')
                ->assertSee('Dashboard')
                ->assertPathIs('/dashboard')
                ->assertAuthenticatedAs($user)
            ;
        });
```

```
class Login extends Page
{
    public function loginUser(Browser $browser, string $email, string $password)
    {
        $browser
            ->type('@email', $email)
            ->type('@password', $password)
            ->press('@button')
        ;
    }
}
```

Regards! :)

Comment: Maybe this answer solves your problem as it was for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281547/1412951

Answer (score 1):

I solved. A small change to the `.env.dusk.local` file helped:

from:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=array
```

to:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

and adding to the `tests/DuskTestCase.php` file:

```
            '--enable-file-cookies',
```

diff:

```
        $options = (new ChromeOptions())->addArguments(collect([
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
+           '--enable-file-cookies',
        ])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
```